.core Entity Framework add custom field to UsersRoles entity using IdentityRole
I'm using .NET Core with MinimalAPI and EntityFramework 8 for a personal project. To manage registration and login, I've used Identity Management out of the box. Now, I need to add some additional information about the relationship between users and roles without resorting to a custom table, but unfortunately, I haven't been able to find documentation on this.
In short, the UsersRole entity should transition from:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsersRoles](
    UserId nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    RoleId nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
)

to:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsersRoles](
    UserId nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    RoleId nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    CustomField1 nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    CustomField2 nvarchar(450) NOT NULL
)

Would anyone be able to assist me in handling this scenario?
Thank you in advance.

Custom the Model
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim<string>> Claims { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin<string>> Logins { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserToken<string>> Tokens { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
   
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}


public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public string CustomField1 { get; set; }
    public string CustomField2 { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}

ApplicationDbContext
public class ApplicationDbContext
    : IdentityDbContext<
        ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string,
        IdentityUserClaim<string>, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>,
        IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b =>
        {
            b.HasMany(e => e.Claims)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId)
                .IsRequired();

            // Each User can have many UserLogins
            b.HasMany(e => e.Logins)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(ul => ul.UserId)
                .IsRequired();

            b.HasMany(e => e.Tokens)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(ut => ut.UserId)
                .IsRequired();

            b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
                .WithOne(e => e.User)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(b =>
        {
            b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
                .WithOne(e => e.Role)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();
        });

    }
}

Program.cs
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

Reference:Add User and Role navigation properties
